# Unicode within Expect/Prefer headers

Tags: http, http-headers

As per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17183124/standard-http-headers-equivalents-for-a-custom-protocol , I am trying to avoid creating new HTTP headers where old ones can do, and I specifically want to support Unicode.

From what I can tell, the "parameter" referenced by [RFC5987](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5987) (which provides a means for Unicode support) is explicitly used within the headers TE, Transfer-Encoding and in Content-Type and Accept (i.e., the media type).

While "Expect" ([RFC2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.20)) and "Prefer" ([draft-snell-http-prefer-18](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-snell-http-prefer-18)) indicate use of parameters of sort, they do not, as far as I can tell, make explicit reference to RFC5987 (nor vice versa), so I am wondering whether these headers may be used to embed Unicode values (within the parameter portion) in a standard-recognized fashion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only header fields that currently support RFC 5987 encoding are Content-Disposition and Link.

Out of curiosity: why do you *need* non-ASCII characters in Expect/Prefer?

Comment: Do you mean that the ones I listed are not supported by implementations or that Content-Disposition and Link were two additional ones that supported it? (The spec seems to suggest the ones I listed would support Unicode.)

Comment: As far as why, I am interested in allowing an arbitrary XPath or CSS Selectors expression to be passed along and be applied to what would normally result at the given URL (fuller details of what I am trying to do at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17183124/standard-http-headers-equivalents-for-a-custom-protocol ). Rather than making a custom header of my own, I thought I could pass it within Expect or probably more usually within Prefer, depending on whether a lack of support of the requested query language would lead to the return of the full document.

Comment: And my hope beyond the XPath or CSS selectors capability is that the WhatWG might consider utilizing it or something similar to allow HTML markup to trigger things like pagination and type-aware data table search interfaces without the author needing to add Ajax libraries (and possibly thereby unduly limit the querying options exposed to the user). By using headers, it could be made to work with static or dynamic pages of whatever URL.

Comment: Header field parameters only support RFC 5987 when they say so. So this is the case for Link and Content-Disposition, but not for those you listed.

Re: Expect/Prefer: these are for feature negotiation, not for passing complex parameters around.

Comment: FYI, I see the reason I got the impression that others were allowed was from section 3.2.1 stating: "In order to include character set and language information, this specification modifies the RFC 2616 grammar to be..." implying to me a general superceding of RFC 2616 rather than merely co-opting it for new specs.